# Why must there be a sequence which converges to (m,b) if they are the arguments of a continuous function, but not a local maximum?

Tags: proof-explanation

I have been reading the paper "[Monty Hall game: a host with limited budget](https://juaa-journal.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/2195-5468-2-2#Sec16)" and trying to follow the arguments the authors make. However, I have been struggling to understand what they outline as Lemma 4.1.

In particular, they state:

> If $g(m,b) = \beta \le 1$, then $(m,b) \ne (1,1)$. Since $g$ is continuous and $(m,b)$ is not a local maxima, there exists a sequence $ \{(m_n,b_n)\}_{n \ge 1}$ which converges to $(m,b)$ with $g(m_n,b_n) > \beta$. In particular, $f(m_n,b_n) > \alpha$.

The Lemma 4.1 itself is as follows:

> For any $\alpha \in \left[ \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3} \right]$, let:
>
> $(m^\ast(\alpha),b^\ast(\alpha)) = \mathop{\arg\max}\limits_{f(m,b) \le \alpha} \ g(m,b)$
>
> $(\tilde{m}(\beta),\tilde{b}(\beta)) = \mathop{\arg\min}\limits_{g(m,b) \ge \beta} \ f(m,b)$
>
> Then $(m^\ast(\alpha),b^\ast(\alpha)) = (\tilde{m}(\beta),\tilde{b}(\beta))$.

They also define:

> $g(m,b) = \frac{m}{3} + \frac{2b}{3}$
>
> $\beta = g(m^\ast(\alpha),b^\ast(\alpha))$

and $f(m,b)$ is another, much longer function that would likely be better interpreted from the paper than if I try to type it out here.

I would like to understand several things:

- How do we know that $(m,b)$ is "not a local maxima" given that $g(m,b) = \beta \le 1$?
- Why does this, along with the continuity of $g$, imply the existence of a sequence as described?

I'm not a mathematician, more of an enthusiast. I feel very lost in this section of the paper and would really appreciate any pointers to improve my understanding of whatever it is I'm not grasping.

Comment: What is $\alpha$?  You mean $g(m,b)\neq 1$?

Comment: The proof is trying to show that something is true for any $\alpha \in \left[ \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3} \right]$.
And no, I actually meant to write $(m,b) \ne (1,1)$ - I'll correct this.

I didn't want to write out the whole Lemma and Proof, for the sake of being concise... but if it is needed to answer the question I can edit/rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(m,b)$ is not a local maximizer of $g$ then for every ball around $(m,b)$, say of radius $1/n$, there exists a point $(m_n, b_n)$ for which $g(m_n, b_n)>g(m,b)$.  This is what it means to not be a local max.  Otherwise there would be some neighborhood where $g(m,b)$ dominated.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. However, I am still struggling to comprehend why there must be a sequence $\{(m_n,b_n)\}_{n \ge 1}$ which converges to $(m,b)$ while still having the property that each $g(m_n,b_n) > g(m,b)$. Having read your answer, it is intuitive that such $(m_n,b_n)$ exist, but why must a sequence of them converge to $(m,b)$ as stated?

Comment: Never mind! I was mistaking sequences for series! No wonder I was confused.